# Function does not get called if the output does not matter

Tags: c++, function, optimization

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream> 

bool function(int a, int b, int &foo) {
    std::cout << "I have been called and I";
    if (a > b)// some magic that maybe changes 'foo'
    {
        foo++;
        std::cout << " did change the variable" << std::endl;
        return true;//inform that i have changed the value
    }
    std::cout << " did NOT change the variable" << std::endl;

    return false;
};

int main()
{
    bool changed = false;
    int bar = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        changed = changed || function(i,4,bar);
    }
    std::cout << "Bar:" << bar;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a function, that does some magic on two variables, depending on that it maybe changes foo variable. It also returns bool whether it changed it or not.

Let's say I put this function in a loop. I call it 10 times and I want to know if any of these calls changed the variable. 
So what I would expect from the code above would be:

```
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did change the variable// 'changed' is now true
I have been called and I did change the variable
I have been called and I did change the variable
I have been called and I did change the variable
I have been called and I did change the variable
Bar:5
```

But, no. Instead I get:

```
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did NOT change the variable
I have been called and I did change the variable// 'changed' is now true
Bar:1
```

In fifth call, the variable got changed, that is correct. But the four remaining calls did not even happen. I get it, because fifth call returned true, then 'changed' variable will always be true no matter what the remaining calls return. I don't care about that, I want it to hold 'true', that's correct after all. But my point is, that those four remaining calls could have changed the 'bar' variable to entirely different value and I need to work with this "correctly changed" value after the loop.

So could someone explain me, please, why is function not called just because it's return value is irrelevant? Because I don't see how that implies that the code inside the function is also irrelevant, especially when some arguments are passed by non-const reference.(For what I know, the function may even terminate the program entirely.)

I'm not looking for solution around this, more like explanation why this even happens.

I compiled this with VS 2015, standard DEBUG and RELEASE mode with same wrong results.

Obviously I get correct output if I eliminate 'changed' variable and just call the function in the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The standard states (emphasis mine):

> **5.15 Logical OR operator**
> ...
>   Unlike `|`, `||` guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation; moreover, *the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to `true`*.

Try swapping the arguments:

```
changed = function(i,4,bar) || changed;
```

Comment: Oh, yea, that solved it. I always thought that the order is irrelevant. Still, isn't it kind of wrong?Because having two functions for both sides: `bool value = foo() || bar();` would result in unpredictable calls for `bar()`.

Comment: Why would it be unpredictable?   Bar would get called if foo returned false.

Comment: I see, they explain it in the link you have provided. Anyway, thanks for help  :)

Comment: @Donnie I meant unpredictable in the way, that I cannot predict how many times `bar` will be called, because it depends on something else, that may not be know at compile time.

Comment: @Quimby This is very much by design, also in many other languages. (Well, in some cases you can even configure the way you want it.) As a workaround, you could consider using `|` instead of `||`. But usually short-circuiting is a good thing.

Comment: @AlexD Thank you, I've read through the link and I can see cases when it could be useful. I will play with it a little bit, the code for my problem needs some polishing anyway. It was just really tough to track this bug(feature) down, beucase I just simply did not expect it. I've read some books and resources online, never seen it anywhere though.

Comment: @Quimby - This is (essentially) the halting problem.